# What other function does PCSK9 have, other than LDL cholesterol control?

Tags: heart-disease, heart, cholesterol, enzyme

I am trying to understand if PCSK9 has other functions in the body, other than the one mentioned in the question title. I know it can be found in different tissues, but I can't find anything about other roles it might have.

I am sorry if I posted this question to the wrong Stack Exchange community.

Comment: Questions on Medical Sciences are required to show prior research. As described in [the help center](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411), this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.

Comment: The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCSK9) mentions other functions and I would imagine the referenced sources would lead to more information.